# Webpack 3 failing on JSX syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I recently upgraded from Webpack v1 to v3 and now the build is not recognising JSX syntax from the app. I followed the documentation for v1 to v2 from [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) and then installed v3.

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const precss = require('precss');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const jsPresets = [
  ['env', {
    targets: {
      chrome: 52,
      browsers: [
        'last 4 versions',
        'safari >= 7',
      ],

    },
  } ],
  'babel-preset-stage-2',
];

const baseConfig = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'antd/dist/antd.css',
    './wp-content/plugins/custom/js/router',
    './wp-content/plugins/custom/js/legacy/header',
    './node_modules/m-react-splitters/lib/splitters.css',
    'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-default.css',
    'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-css-effects/flip.css',
    'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-css-effects/bouncyflip.css',
    'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './wp-content/plugins/custom/js'),
    filename: 'custom.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          'css-loader?-url',
          'postcss-loader',
        ]
      }),
    }, {
        // whatwg-fetch use Promsie which IE11 doesn't support
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [/whatwg-.*/],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
      }, {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: jsPresets,
          plugins: [
            ['import', { libraryName: 'antd' }],
            'transform-class-properties',
            'transform-es2015-arrow-functions',
          ],
        },
      },
    }],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '../css/custom.css',
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react',
      Intl: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.Intl!intl',
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = baseConfig;
```

Error message thrown on terminal after webpack tries to bundle:

[image: Webpack failure]

I am not sure what is wrong here, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in your presesets you are not using a react preset. You will need to install babel-preset-react like so:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-react
```

And then in your presets simply add "react" and it should transpile.